# Using average in array formula

Tags: google-sheets, split, average, array-formulas, flatten

I have the following table structure

| Name | Role | rank 1 | rank 2 | rank 3 | rank 4 | rank 5 | rank 6 |  | Average |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jon | Admin | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 8 | 9 |  |  |
| Tomas | Accountant | 3 | 2 | 2 | 9 | 3 | 3 |  |  |
| Ellie | Admin | 2 | 9 | 7 | 3 | 9 | 1 |  |  |
| Sam | Sales | 4 | 7 | 3 | 9 | 1 | 8 |  |  |

The actual table has circa 2k rows, and has a lot more columns, before I was using the following formula then dragging down.

```
=IF(B2 = "Admin", AVERAGE(C2,D2,F2), AVERAGE(C2,F2,G2,H2))
```

But this was really slow (especially as other sheets are doing something similar) almost rendering the sheet to be unusable.

Unsure how to convert the above formula into an array formula so I just need to enter one fomula for a cells.

I've tried

```
=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(IF(B2:B = "Admin", AVERAGE(C2:C,D2:D,F2:F), AVERAGE(C2:C,F2:F,G2:G,H2:H)), ""))
```

But I get the following result

| Name | Role | rank 1 | rank 2 | rank 3 | rank 4 | rank 5 | rank 6 |  | Average |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jon | Admin | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 8 | 9 |  | 5.583333333 |
| Tomas | Accountant | 3 | 2 | 2 | 9 | 3 | 3 |  | 5.3125 |
| Ellie | Admin | 2 | 9 | 7 | 3 | 9 | 1 |  | 5.583333333 |
| Sam | Sales | 4 | 7 | 3 | 9 | 1 | 8 |  | 5.3125 |

When it should be

| Name | Role | rank 1 | rank 2 | rank 3 | rank 4 | rank 5 | rank 6 |  | Average |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jon | Admin | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 8 | 9 |  | 6.333333333 |
| Tomas | Accountant | 3 | 2 | 2 | 9 | 3 | 3 |  | 4.5 |
| Ellie | Admin | 2 | 9 | 7 | 3 | 9 | 1 |  | 4.666666667 |
| Sam | Sales | 4 | 7 | 3 | 9 | 1 | 8 |  | 5.5 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
=INDEX(IF(B2:B="Admin", 
 QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(ROW(C2:C)&"×"&{C2:D, F2:F}), "×"),
 "select avg(Col2) 
  group by Col1  
  label avg(Col2)''"), 
 QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(ROW(C2:C)&"×"&{C2:C, F2:H}), "×"),
 "select avg(Col2) 
  group by Col1  
  label avg(Col2)''")))
```

[image]

Comment: OMG, I was just about to post. Oh well... this would probably work too... Your trying to apply this to the entire column. Use Filter to minimize the calculations to only be the area you're using. Regarding the average, this is unfortunately difficult when using sums and beverages. Try something simple like this:

`=FILTER(If(B2:B="Admin",(C2:C+D2:D+F2:F)/3,(C2:C+F2:F+G2:G+H2:H)/4),A2:A<>"")`

Comment: @player0 This worked perfectly, thank you. If I wanted to add an `OR` operator instead of an `IF` how would I do that? I tried `=INDEX(IF(OR(B2:B="Admin", B2:B="Sales"),` but the value is always truth, even if column B is neither `Admin` or `Sales`?

Comment: @mcclosa either: `IF((B2:B="Admin") + (B2:B="Sales"),` or: `IF(REGEXMATCH(B2:B, "Admin|Sales"),`